# Need to display custom text in invoice and shipment view (sales_order_invoice_view) in Payment information section

Tags: magento2

Need to  display custom text in invoice and shipment view (sales_order_invoice_view) in Payment information section in magento 2.3[[image: Need this custom text in order invoice view and order shipment view in payment section[1]]

Comment: Add Proper description as well as screenshots so everyone can understand it properly and give you quick answer for your question.

Comment: @NiravPatel as per image need to display this text in order invoice view and order shipment view